# Wtforms-alchemy field order

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, wtforms

I'm using wtforms-alchemy in my Tornado application to render SQLAlchemy models to HTML forms like this:

```
class UserProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        only = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name']
```

It works just fine, but the fields on the form are in order last_name, username, first_name, which could be kinda confusing to user. Is there a way to set specific order of generated form's fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did what [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18475322/892040) post suggested, and its been working flawlessly for me.

Briefly, add a class keyword that specifies the correct ordering, then update _unbound_fields from **iter** with fields in correct order.

Answer (score 1):

You should put rendering of form in template.

like

```
{{ form.username }}
{{ form.first_name }}
{{ form.last_name }}
```

Comment: Thanks for response! However, if only it would be so simple...
See, I'm rendering all the forms (I have quite a plenty of them) in automatic manner, like that:
`{% for field in form %}
  <dt>{% raw field.label %}</dt>
  <dd>{% raw field %}</dd>
{% end %}`

In fact, the only reason I'm using wtforms-alchemy library is to avoid boilerplate like the one you've provided.
So my initial question boils down to this: how do I provide field order without any explicit form enumeration in template?

Answer (score 1):

Solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/18475322/892040 did not work for me when inheriting from `ModelForm`. However, this did work:

```
class ItemReview(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
    _field_order = ['field1', 'field2']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ItemReview, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        field_order = getattr(ItemReview, '_field_order')
        visited = []
        if field_order:
            new_fields = OrderedDict()
            for field_name in field_order:
                if field_name in self._fields:
                    new_fields[field_name] = self._fields[field_name]
                    visited.append(field_name)
            for field_name in self._fields:
                if field_name in visited:
                    continue
                new_fields[field_name] = self._fields[field_name]
            self._fields = new_fields
```